# Encrypt and Decrypt Microsoft.Entityframeworkcore.sqlite Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I'm Working on Xamarin Forms .Net Standard 2.0 using `Microsoft.Entityframeworkcore.sqlite`. 
                         I have a requirement encrypt and decrypt the whole database not only the fields.
                         I tried using crypteron nuget package but no luck. Could anyone suggest how to encrypt and decrypt.
                         I have implemented the .net Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) and System.Security.Cryptography which is for the specific filed but not for whole database level.
[AES](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/encrypt.html)

Comment: What do you mean by encrypt the database?

Comment: @viveknuna by encrypting database I mean when the application is closed the database should be encrypted and when the application is open the database should be decrypted. Similar to the SQLite.Net.Cipher for Entityframework.

Comment: So, you would like to encrypt the whole file that contains your sqlite db after you closed the db and decrypt the file before opening it?

Comment: @michael yeah...